# Slide content with page up and down

Tags: slide

A few small questions on this web page I am putting together.

http://dansiop.com/guyc/our-team/

I am looking to get the content that appears when you click on an image to slide with the mouse as you scroll down. Not sure if this is possible, if so can anyone help.

I have tried looking but as I am such a n00b to jquery I'm not sure what I am looking for. I found some code that used the tag slide and it was not what i wanted at all so not sure what the command would be.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing what you are wanting to accomplish. What do you mean slide with the mouse?  Do you mean, when you scroll the page down, you want the content to always be visible? or do you want it to actually move when you move the mouse on the page? or move when you move the mouse over the content?

Comment: When you click on one of the suers their profile will appear on the right hand pane. If I scroll down to view users photos lower down the content form the user I just clicked stays at the page, it is static, i want the profle to follow my window. If I scroll to the bottom of my page to view the last 3 profiles and click on an image their profile will appear off screen, it will be at the top, i want it to appear when the screen is and if i scroll back to the top i would like the content in the right pane to follow me. Does this make sense?

Comment: Sorry i answered before reading your whole reply, i want the content to always be visible when i scroll.

Comment: Do you have gchat?  we aren't suppose to have extended comments on a post.  We should probably move over to chat if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your prof_1, prof_2, etc, in a wrapper I'm going to call this wrapper prof_wrapper

```
<div id="prof_wrapper"></div>
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
   var orig_t = jQuery("#prof_wrapper").offset().top;
   var mt = jQuery("#main").offset().top;
   var mh = jQuery("#main").outerHeight();

   jQuery(document).bind("scroll", function(event){
      var ph = jQuery("#prof_wrapper").outerHeight();
      var mo = (mt+mh) - jQuery(document).scrollTop();
      var t = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
      if(mo <= ph){  //Find out if the #main element's offset top plus it's height minus the scroll position is less than the prof_wrapper's height; if it is, leave the prof_wrapper at the bottom of the #main element
          jQuery("#prof_wrapper").css({'position':'absolute', 'bottom':'0px', 'top':'auto'});
      }else if(t >= orig_t){ //Otherwise, if we have scrolled past the prof_wrapper, make the prof_wrapper follow us down
        jQuery("#prof_wrapper").css({'position':'fixed', 'top':'0px', 'bottom':'auto'});
      }else{ //We are probably at the top of the page, so reset the original positioning
        jQuery("#prof_wrapper").css({'position':'relative', 'top':'0px', 'bottom':'auto'});
      }
    });
});
```

You need to add - position:relative to your #main element, then I think this should be pretty close.  Take a look at my comment about the padding and margin on the prof_wrapper.

The positioning of absolute, assumes that #main is the first parent element to have a position assigned to it; if so, then it will use this as the positioning for the bottom.

Something like that?

Comment: Thanks man, I have implemented this but something isn't quite right, could you take a quick look and see what I have done wrong? http://dansiop.com/guyc/our-team/

Comment: I changed the code a bit...That should have been a stationary top for the element.  What was happening was that, once the top was set to 0, it never changed.  So we actually needed to get the original offset top, and use that.  Now, this doesn't solve the problem of it running down the page past the #main content.  So we need to add something else for that.  But make these changes first, and I'll add that later.

Comment: Hi thanks, changed the code and added top : 50px to give some buffer but its not working as smoothly as i thought it would. is there something we can add for the smoothness . thanks again, really appreciate this.

Comment: another thing you could do, would be to remove the padding or margin from the bottom of the ".click" element above the prof_wrapper, and add that space as top padding to the prof_wrapper, and go back to the original code, that will be the most natural thing to do.

Comment: how can i stop it coming out of the box, if i scroll down the content comes out of the content box, it goes over the footer

Comment: dude, you didn't update the code.  Try my code above, that's what it's suppose to stop

Comment: http://dansiop.com/guyc/our-team/ Still not quite working, could have anything to do with the css

Comment: I noted above that you'll have to make the #main have a position of relative.  I'll take a look at it again in a second.  That should work  or be very close.

Comment: and take out the 40px buffer on the code!  after it's working, then mess around with it, but please don't ask me to help you, then add in your own stuff, and tell me it's not working.

Comment: Ok sorry man, I have changed #main to position: relative, taken the 40px buffer out and removed the 100% height from the prof_wrapper. I don't think its quite working still.

Comment: Check the code above...That should do it I think.  the ph wasn't being reevaluated and since it began at 0, it wasn't doing anything productive.  I also changed a few of the css assignments so look at those too.

Comment: Ok I think I actually love you. Its working! Just one more question, the content in the right panel is stuck to the top of the window while scrolling, how can I give it a small padding so it looks a bit better. I wanted to add the maybe 20 px padding but don't know where to apply this to not mess it up.

Comment: I can't up vote you as i only have a rating of 12 and it says i need 15. I chose your answer -anything else you want me to do?

Comment: You just need to add a top padding to the prof_wrapper.  That will be the easiest thing to do.  If you want to do it in the code....I'll let  you play around with the math and figure that one out ;)  A hint would to take into consideration the scroll position and the extra padding you want to add.

Comment: Heh, and remove the <div id="prof_wrapper"> from the top of your javascript code

Comment: Ok thanks I have it working now - love it - Thanks a lot - I will leave you alone now. I will select this answer now.